# CustomSimpleAdapter and row color based on text conditions

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

i am doing a ListView with SimpleAdapter.. i am trying to set textcolour based on the data passed.

in the main activity:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();     

    for(int i=0;i<Db.risposteDate.size();i++){
            Esame e = Db.risposteDate.get(i);

            HashMap<String,Object> EsamiMap=new HashMap<String, Object>();

            EsamiMap.put("num", e.getDomandaNum()); 
            EsamiMap.put("testo", Html.fromHtml(e.getTesto()+"<br />")); 
            EsamiMap.put("ris", e.getRispostaData());
            data.add(EsamiMap);  
    }


    String[] from={"num","testo","ris"}; //dai valori contenuti in queste chiavi
    int[] to={R.id.tv1,R.id.tv2,R.id.tv3};//agli id delle view
//costruzione dell adapter
    customAdapter adapter=new customAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    data,
                    R.layout.riga_lista, 
                    from,
                    to);
((ListView)findViewById(R.id.tabellaRisultati)).setAdapter(adapter);
```

i created a customAdapter:

```
class customAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

public customAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);   
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    return view;
}
}
```

but i have no idea how work getView()... i want that i read a value inside data and if is correct i want textcolour RED.

the main problem is that i don't know how "look" inside data.

Comment: have You tried http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#getItem%28int%29 ?

Comment: If my answer resolved your question, please upvote. I gived you +1 for the question right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered to a similar question a few days before. See my custom adapter, there is a getView method inside.

If you have questiosn, feel free to ask.

Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525785/how-to-use-custom-list-adapter-for-android